# MySQL inserting same value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I stumbled upon weird behavior in MySQL.

Lets say that I have only one record in table

```
| id | oib |
|----|-----|
| 1  |  5  |
```

Field *oib* is unique.

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `oib`) VALUES (NULL, '6')
```

I get following exception

```
Duplicate entry '5' for key 'oib_UNIQUE'
```

And this keeps going on no matter what value I try to save.
Anyone have idea what could cause this. I've never seen it.

**UPDATE**:

Here is CREATE TABLE statement:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` int(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oib` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `oib_UNIQUE` (`oib`)
)
```

Comment: Without your CREATE TABLE statement, I don't think there's much we can say - not that that will stop us!

Comment: I added table definition

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert null value in id primary key

Comment: @strawberry, that fiddle is not quite working the way you think or pretending it is. It is not putting a null in the pk you know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your table have one record for oib = '5' ?

You cannot insert null into primary key.

Comment: Yes, table has only that record